# How store 2d matrix values in a variable?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as df
from numpy import asarray
from numpy import save
files=np.load('arr.npy',allow_pickle=True)

#print(files)
data=df.DataFrame(files)

type(data)
rr=data.shape[0]

for i in range(0,rr):

      res=data[0][i]
```

after running res variable contains last element

but i want all the values

so tell me how to store all the 2d matrix  values in python ??

data variable is the dataframe

it contains 9339 rows and 2 columns

but i want 1st column it is the 32x32 matrix

how to store values res variable

Comment: i want answer for this question

Comment: mail: sachinmuthiah@gmail.com

Comment: please help rectify this code

Comment: Make a list `res = []` and inside `for` loop, append to that list `res.append(data[0][i])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that `res = data[0][i]` initializes a new variable `res` on the first iteration of the loop (when `i` is `0`), but then keeps reassigning its value to the value in the next row (staying on column 0).

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but it sounds like you just want the first column in a separate variable? Here is how to get the first column, as a pandas series and/or plain list, with a smaller example (9 rows and 2 columns)

```
import pandas as pd
random_data = np.random.rand(9,2)
data_df = pd.DataFrame(random_data)
print(data_df)

# this gets the first column as a pandas series. Change index from 0 to get another column.
print('\nfirst column:')
first_col = data_df[data_df.columns[0]]
print(first_col)

# if you want a plain list instead of a series
print('\nfirst column as list:')
print(first_col.tolist())
```

Output:

```
          0         1
0  0.218237  0.323922
1  0.806697  0.371456
2  0.526571  0.993491
3  0.403947  0.299652
4  0.753333  0.542269
5  0.365885  0.534462
6  0.404583  0.514687
7  0.298897  0.637910
8  0.453891  0.234333

first column:
0    0.218237
1    0.806697
2    0.526571
3    0.403947
4    0.753333
5    0.365885
6    0.404583
7    0.298897
8    0.453891
Name: 0, dtype: float64

first column as list:
[0.21823726509923325, 0.8066974875381492, 0.526571422644495, 0.40394686954663594, 0.7533330239460391, 0.36588470364914194, 0.4045827678891364, 0.2988970490642284, 0.45389073978613426]
```

Comment: okay thats good  but my problem is  in my npy file like 
   you 2 columns labels are 0 and1

Comment: okay that good  but my problem is  in my npy file like 
   you 2 columns labels are 0 and 1 in column 0 every row contains 32x32 matrix i want to increase size of every matrix size into 128x128  in the 0 column itself

Comment: pls mail me i provide the npy file for you its challenging one but you can get the output

Comment: I believe it does not matter what data type is in the cell -- it is the same concept as above. You can store matrices in each DataFrame cell. If you want to want to perform a transformation on a column of each cell, in a uniform fashion, you may benefit from an `apply`: see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: thanks im completed with using repeat function but my output (9339,128,128) but i want shape like 9339,0   0 Means column under column all the 128x128 matrix is going to stored like 0th index 128x128 matrix under the 1st index 128x128 upto 9338 index values how to do  output maybe dataframe

Comment: thanks im completed with using repeat function but my output (9339,128,128) but i want shape like (9339,0 )  0 Means column  label under column all the 128x128 matrix is going to stored like 0th index 128x128 matrix under the 1st index 128x128 upto 9338 index values   how to do  ?output maybe in  dataframe